# How to place inset axes of image in upper right corner

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to place an inset axes exactly in the upper right of my existing axes. This is usually very simple if you use the `bbox_to_anchor` keyword in conjunction with the `transform` of the parent axes.

```py
axins = inset_axes(ax, width="40%", height="40%", 
                   borderpad=0, 
                   bbox_to_anchor=(0,0,1,1), 
                   bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
```

But in my case, the inset axes contains an image using `ax.imshow()`. This will always set the aspect ratio of the inset axes to the aspect ratio of the image *which is what I want*. However, if the aspect ratio of `ax` and the image do not match, then the image will be added not completely in the corner of the parent axes:

[image: incorrect placing]

I know that this is because I am using the transform of the parent axes and that it is because of imshow shortening the width of the image/inset axes, but no matter what I use to calculate the offset that needs to be added in `bbox_to_anchor`, I cannot figure out the formula that gives me the right amount to add in `bbox_to_anchor=(0+num,0,1,1)`.

It must be something obtained from `ax.get_position()`, multiplied by the percentage (`width=40%, height=40%`) and something involving the transform `transform=ax.transAxes`, but I do not know what to multiply with what in order to find the correct value for `num`.

How do I calculate the offset so that I can provide the right value for `num` to `bbox_to_anchor`?

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
import numpy as np


X,Y,R = 200,200,3
pixels = np.random.uniform(0,1,X*Y*R)
image = pixels.reshape(X, Y, R)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))

axins = inset_axes(ax, width="40%", height="40%", borderpad=0, bbox_to_anchor=(0,0,1,1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
axins.imshow(image)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already identified that the aspect ratio is what's preventing from positioning your image in the corner.

If you handle situations where `fig_width > fig_height` and `fig_height > fig_width` separately, you'll be able to compute an `x_offset` (resp. `y_offset`) based on height, width and the relative size of your image:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
import numpy as np

X,Y,R = 200,200,3

fig_width_in = 6
fig_height_in = 4
rel_im_size = 0.4

pixels = np.random.uniform(0,1,X*Y*R)
image = pixels.reshape(X, Y, R)

x_offset = (fig_width_in-fig_height_in)/fig_width_in * rel_im_size/2 if fig_width_in > fig_height_in else 0
y_offset = (fig_height_in-fig_width_in)/fig_height_in * rel_im_size/2 if fig_height_in > fig_width_in else 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(fig_width_in,fig_height_in))

axins = inset_axes(ax, width=f'{rel_im_size*100}%', height=f'{rel_im_size*100}%', borderpad=0,
                    bbox_to_anchor=(0 + x_offset, 0 + y_offset, 1, 1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
axins.imshow(image)

plt.show()
```

Output for `fig_width=6`, `fig_height=4` and `rel_im_size=0.4`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to refine this into a class that can display images of molecules generated with RDKit from so-called SMILES strings. Should I credit you or something when I put it on GitHub?

Comment: You don't need to but feel free to do it :)

Comment: @J.Doe you specifically asked for a formula but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77355163/13525512) made me aware of [`set_anchor`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_anchor.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_anchor). Meaning you could save the formula and simply use `anchor = 'N' if fig_height_in > fig_width_in else 'E'` then `axins.set_anchor(anchor)`