# place a PNG right above an axes object

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I have a Matplotlib figure with three axes, placed above one another. Above the top `axes` object I want to place an image that I enclose in an `inset_axes()` 'box'. The image should as be as wide as the `axes` object (and its height should be scaled accordingly compared to its original proportions), and it should connect seamlessly to the top of the `axes` object (so with no whitespace between the bottom of the image and the top of the `axes` object). Like this (the black box is the `axes` object; the red box the image):

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=True)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    if i == 0:
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(MY_DIR, img_name), formats=["png"]
        axin = ax.inset_axes([0.0, ???, 1.0, 1.0])
        axin.imshow(img, alpha=1)
        axin.axis("off")
```

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html), the `bounds` argument for `inset_axes()` takes four values: "Lower-left corner of inset Axes, and its width and height". I found out that I can use 1.0 for the width and height, which makes the image as wide as the `axes`, keeping its proportions. The x-coordinate is also obvious: it should be 0, so that the left of the image aligns with the start of the x-axis. But -- I cannot figure out what the y-coordinate should be.

If I set `y` to 0, the image is centered vertically along the y-axis of the `axes` object:

[image]

If I set it to 0.5, then its middle aligns with the top of the y-axis. Still not what I want:

[image]

How can I get the result that I want? I cannot make it make sense. Is there a way to tell matplotlib that the bottom of the image should align with the top of the `axes`?

(I should mention that I asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345556/get-dimensions-of-pil-image-to-help-placing-it-relative-to-axes-object?), but that seems to have been a dead end.)

Comment: Have you tried `0.5 + rel_im_height`? where `rel_im_height` is your relative image height? Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324061/how-to-place-inset-axes-of-image-in-upper-right-corner/77324970#77324970)

Comment: @Tranbi wrong link

Comment: @Daviid Thanks for the quick notification! I was able to fix it :)

Comment: @Tranbi Do you have an idea how to get the relative image height? The problem is that I don't know it. I only have the size of the original image in pixels. I can calculate the size of the axes in pixels, and with this information I can calculate the factor with which the image is rescaled to fit the axes, and then its height (rescaled), and finally its height relative to the axes. However, I tried this just now, and the result is not as expected. No idea where this went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `y` to 1, because that is the top of the axes.  Then set the `anchor` of the inset axes to "S" (for south) so that, once the inset axes is resized to account for the aspect ratio, it is still attached to the top of the main axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.random.random((5, 25))

fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(5, 7))
ax_ins = ax_arr[0].inset_axes([0, 1, 1, 1])
ax_ins.imshow(img)
ax_ins.set_anchor("S")
ax_ins.axis("off")

plt.savefig("test.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed much simpler than computing relative height! +1

Comment: @RuthC Wow, perfect. One line. I knew it had to be possible to do it in such a simple way, but never came across this in my search. Thanks!