matplotlib path patch outside axes
I want to create a tab for a plot. I have a PathPatch object that I would like to place just above the top spine (i.e. outside the plotting area). Secondly I would like a method that dynamically adjusts the width of the path in accordance with the width of the text.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.path as mpath

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Path = mpath.Path
path_data = [
    (Path.MOVETO, (0, 0)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (0, 1.0)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (1, 1.0)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (1, 1)),

    (Path.LINETO, (4, 1)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (4, 1)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (5, 1.05)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (5, 0)),
    (Path.CLOSEPOLY, (0, 0)),
    ]
codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
path = mpath.Path(verts, codes)
patch = mpatches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='r', alpha=0.5)

ax.add_patch(patch)

x, y = zip(*path.vertices)
#line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'go-')


text_obj = plt.text(x = 0.75, y = 0.35, s = 'Text', fontsize = 32)

ax.grid()
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()



I think you need the patch to be within an axes.  I suggest putting an inset axes right above the main one and turning the frame off, similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77352821/place-a-png-right-above-an-axes-object/77355163#77355163

Using @RuthC's comment as a starting point:
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path as mpPath

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

fig.set_size_inches(10, 8)

ax.set_xlim(-1, 6)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 2)
ax.grid()

width = ax.get_xlim()[1] - ax.get_xlim()[0]
height = ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0]

ax_ins = ax.inset_axes([0, 1, 1, 0.8])

path_data = [
    (mpPath.MOVETO, (0, 0)),
    (mpPath.CURVE4, (0, 1)),
    (mpPath.CURVE4, (1, 1)),
    (mpPath.CURVE4, (1, 1)),
    (mpPath.LINETO, (4, 1)),
    (mpPath.CURVE4, (4, 1)),
    (mpPath.CURVE4, (5, 1)),
    (mpPath.CURVE4, (5, 0)),
    (mpPath.CLOSEPOLY, (0, 0)),
]

codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
verts = [(v[0] / 5, v[1] / 4) for v in verts]

path = mpPath(verts, codes)
patch = mpatches.PathPatch(path, facecolor="r", alpha=0.5)

bbox = patch.get_extents()

ax_ins.add_patch(patch)
ax_ins.set_anchor("S")
ax_ins.axis("off")

ax_ins.text(
    x=bbox.x0 + bbox.width / 2,
    y=bbox.y0 + bbox.height / 2,
    horizontalalignment="center",
    verticalalignment="center",
    s="Text",
    fontsize=24,
)

ax_ins.text(x=0.5, y=0.45, s="Title", fontsize=24, horizontalalignment="center")

fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1, 1.3])
fig.savefig("plot.png")


Note: The layout gets a little funky with this approach. This is why the title is being added manually rather than using ax.title().

No need to create extra Axes instances, you can simply set clip_on=False when you create the PathPatch, to allow it to plotted outside the Axes limits.
From the docs:

Artist.set_clip_on(b)
Set whether the artist uses clipping.
When False, artists will be visible outside the Axes which can lead to unexpected results.
Parameters:
b bool

For example:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.path as mpath

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)

Path = mpath.Path
path_data = [
    (Path.MOVETO, (0, 5)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (0, 6.0)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (1, 6.0)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (1, 6)),

    (Path.LINETO, (4, 6)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (4, 6)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (5, 6.05)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (5, 5)),
    (Path.CLOSEPOLY, (0, 5)),
    ]
codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
path = mpath.Path(verts, codes)
patch = mpatches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='r', alpha=0.5, clip_on=False)

ax.add_patch(patch)


x, y = zip(*path.vertices)
#line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'go-')


text_obj = plt.text(x = 2.5, y = 5.35, s = 'Text', fontsize = 32, ha='center')

ax.grid()
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
plt.show()


